# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast when http post the list array

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a selectedItems in the list:

```
List<String> _selectedItems = [];
```

Then, I want to pass this _selectedItems like this:

```
Future<void> _filterItem(List<String> _selectedItems) async {
    ProgressDialog pr = ProgressDialog(context,
        type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: false);
    pr.style(message: "Loading...");
    await pr.show();
    http.post("https://one.com/myapp/php/load_data.php", body: {

      "_selectedItems":_selectedItems,

    }).then((res) {
      if (res.body == "nodata") {
        setState(() {
          print("No Found");
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          var extractdata = json.decode(res.body);
          tutordata = extractdata["mydata"];
        });
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
    await pr.hide();
  }
```

Passing this  `_selectedItems`  throws the error  `type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

body: takes `<String, String>`
and you are trying to give it `<String, List<String>>`

convert your `List<String>` to `JSON string`  using `jsonEncode`

Answer (score 0):

When exploring the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) for `http.post()`, you can see what types the `body` can be:

> body sets the body of the request. It can be a String, a List or a Map<String, String>

Right now, your code is passing a `Map<String, List<String>>` to the `body`, when it needs to be `Map<String, String>` instead:

```dart
http.post("https://one.com/myapp/php/load_data.php", body: {
      "_selectedItems":_selectedItems,
    })
```

You can do this:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

http.post("https://one.com/myapp/php/load_data.php", body: {
      "_selectedItems": jsonEncode(_selectedItems),
    })
```

Btw, you can make some improvement on the code. First, for the logic flow, it's often good practice to separate the result of an API call to a `setState()` since it would be easier to anticipate the flow of the app. You can read more about `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder`, as well as `BLoC` pattern.

For the clean code, you can apply principles from the [styling documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) as well. Some adjustment can be made like using CamelCase instead of normal case, so `extractData` instead of `extractdata`.